# Pseudo elements and button tag: how to prevent the pseudo element from being clickable?

Tags: html, css

I've got a button (`<button>` tag, but rendered like a link) inserted at the end of a line of text.  I need to make a clear separation between the button and the text, so I'm using a `:before` pseudo element with a `content: "—";` property to achieve that.  So far so good.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Anto/UPjQL/

The problem is that the content of the pseudo element behaves just like the button itself: when hovering it, the `default` cursor becomes a `pointer` cursor and the element is underlined.  That makes sense, but I'd like to prevent that behavior and let it appear just like a regular text char.

Any idea ?

---

I *know* that wrapping the button inside, say, a `span` element and *then* giving the `:before` properties to that wrapper would be a more elegant solution, but in this case I can't afford it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/UPjQL/3/

```
.button-rendered-as-a-link {
    position: relative; <-------------
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
    -moz-border-radius: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: none;
    border-radius: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #8A89BA;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 2em; <-------------
}
.button-rendered-as-a-link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-rendered-as-a-link:before {
    content:" — ";
    position: absolute; <-------------
    right: 100%; <-------------
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: grey;
    cursor: default !important;
    pointer-events: none; <-------------
}
```

The arrows represent the stuff I've added.

I've basically removed the pseudo element from the flow by using position: absolute. That made the button's width equal to what it would be without the psuedo element, and therefore, it's underline equal to no more than that width. The left and right properties put them back in place.

Then, as to not trigger a hover on the button I set the pseudo element's pointer-events to none. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/.

Comment: Hooo, that's clever :)  And I didn't know about the pointer-events property.  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I would just use JavaScript in your case, the `insertBefore` method should do the trick quite nicely!

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button-rendered-as-a-link");
for (key in buttons)
  try{
   buttons[key].parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(" - "),buttons[key]);
  }catch(e){}// this may throw an error?
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I can't use JS either for this problem.  Thanks anyway !